# Email-only hosted in Godaddy and website hosted in my server

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, godaddy

so there is the thing.

The domain registar is Godaddy.I want the email account to stay in godaddy and the website to another machine.
i changed the domains nameservers from godaddy panel to point my server.
great A records work fine.

i created these MX and CNAME records on my server :

- domain.com         MX (10) mailstore1.europe.secureserver.net.
- domain.com         MX (0) smtp.secureserver.net.
- email.domain.com.    CNAME   email.europe.secureserver.net.
- smtp.domain.com. CNAME   smtp.secureserver.net.
- mail.domain.com. CNAME   email.secureserver.net.

and deleted the default mail.domain.com Cname,

which from godaddy seemed correct , but no email is sent or received..its been almost 24 hours and the http traffic is OK only 2 hours since the nameservers changed

any advice or commands to looks for the right configuration?
cheers

Comment: Your DNS records look fine. You should check that your new mail provider is configured correctly for your domain.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure there is an A record for smtp.domain.com. ?

The RFC states:

> MX records cause type A additional section processing for the host
>   specified by EXCHANGE.

Comment: hey thanks , can you explain further what i should do?